# Unlocking iPhone 7 without touch the Home Button

Tags: unlock, iphone, touch-id

I've been running for 4 years and today I've encountered problem when I wanted to run with my iPhone 7. I was using the armband with my iPhone 5 and iPhone 6s and everything was great. I've placed my iPhone 7 in 6S's armband and it's impossible to unlock the screen because of the thin layer of transparent material. I've always been running with my screen off so when I was finishing my run I used to unlock my phone and stop the activity when I stopped (without removing it from the armband)
Is there any way to unlock the iPhone 7 without physically touching the Home Button? I'd like to do as I used to in iPhone 6s - touch the home button and unlock the screen by typing the password (I know that Touch ID doesn't work in that case)

Edit: Ok, it's possible with assistive touch. Any other options?

Comment: @fsb But how am I supposed to use Home button when it's behind the plastic cover? iPhone 7's home button doesn't work that way.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.  I forgot about that capacitive home button.  I'll delete my comment.